# Regex replace for PHP $_POST and $_GET variables

Tags: php, regex

I would like to apply a function to every PHP POST or GET variable:

```
$_GET["some_variable"] -> some_function($_GET["some_variable"])

$_POST["some_variable"] -> some_function($_POST["some_variable"])
```

Any suggestion for the regex expression to match and replace those occurrences in my files?

Comment: Wait - do you want to _modify your code_, or just call a function on every $_GET/$_POST key? Modifying the code could be risky, as it could result in attempting to write to function calls or various other undesirable or syntactically invalid behaviors, like function calls suddenly appearing inside double-quoted strings where they can't execute.

Comment: I think he/she wants to modify the code.

Comment: Don't do that. The next person or the future you will hate you for that. Changing those super globals is `E_BAAAAD`.

Comment: Also I am fairly certain this is an XY problem.

Comment: Pretty much any decent IDE will have built in functions to allow you to do search/replace across all files in a library.

Comment: @PeeHaa, it's actually fairly common when writing code where you can't guarantee that magic_quotes will be off to strip slashes in the event you find magic_quotes are on.  Magic Quotes are more evil.

Comment: Magic quotes have been deprecated for a loooong time and removed from the language a long time.

Comment: @PeeHaa, yes, they've been deprecated for good reason...there are still millions of servers out there running PHP 5.3 and below prior to its removal in 5.4...and I've had the unfortune of having code get installed on a machine that is running magic_quotes and having to add in code to strip them out since they couldn't be turned off due to other code which relied on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_map` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to call a function on each element of an array:

```
$modifiedGet = array_map(some_function, $_GET);

$modifiedPost = array_map(some_function, $_POST);
```

Comment: @user2703038, array_map is not recursive to my knowledge, so if you might be passing in arrays (e.g. checkboxes or multi-select), then it might not work for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. Consider some code like

```
<?php
   $_POST['override'] = 'some override value';
```

Unless you want to teach your replacement function PHP syntax rules, you'll end up with

```
<?php
    some_function($_POST['override']) = 'some override value';
```

which is a syntax error: `Can't use function return value in write context`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply. The OP wasn't trying to do a search/replace of code...just overwriting the value in the get|post.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to downvote say why in the comment so I can fix a mistake if there is one. To my knowledge, this is a better method to call than the accepted answer since it is recursive and will work on sub-arrays.  If it's not, I'd like to know why.

You can use array_walk_recursive to call a function for each value in an array:

```
function walk_function(&$value) {
    $value = some_function($value);
}
array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'walk_function');
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'walk_function');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

This has an advantage over `array_map` in that it is recursive and will call the function for arrays within the array.  For example, if you submit checkboxes or multi-select there will be sub-arrays that may need the same processing done on them.

Comment: You can't assume what is the target type of `some_function`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I've defined `some_function`, does that suffice?

Comment: Sorry, but no. You don't know what `some_function` is. `some_function` is only know by the OP, you can't assume what it is, and you need to build an answer with this fact.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, ah, so what you're saying is if the questioner uses the function foo, even though it is a generic placeholder, from then on I have to assume that foo() is a real method and I can't use it for my own methods and have to use bar.  I'll try to remember that for future reference.  Thx.

Comment: Exactly, you don't know what `some_function` is, and you don't know what it does and what are the types of the array items (are they numbers, strings, arrays, objects? If they are arrays, must be each levels changed or not). To be short, you can't assume that a possible multidimensionnal array must be changed for all its levels.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I'm fine with only using `some_function` the way the OP used it, and I've corrected that. However, you also can't assume that the OP doesn't need to recursively walk through arrays. If the OP were, in fact, trying to get rid of magic_quotes for all POST/GET vars, then it would be necessary to use the recursive call. `array_map` could also fail if `some_function` does something that will break on an array value. So, to mark an answer down for the possibility that it doesn't match the OP's use-case when that use-case is not specified doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: "you also can't assume that the OP doesn't need to recursively walk through arrays", I am agree, but in this case, the recursive walk is a job for `some_function`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, "but in this case, the recursive walk is a job for `some_function`" ... and you know this because the OP told you this in a private conversation somewhere???